# Aerospike растет количество коннектов

Tags: golang, aerospike

Растет количество коннектов со временем ( ощущение что он их не закрывает после использования)

Настройки клиента и сервера идут по умолчанию.
Aerospike состоит из кластера в 5 нод.

На го работа строится по следующему принципу очень много запросов на обновление и добавление записей ( через воркеры и очереди)
(простенькая DMP, записей около 300 миллионов профилей, рпс в районе 10-15к в пике)

обнаружили проблему что со временем растет количество конектов. После чего падают сервисы - что видно на графике. Сталкивался ли кто либо с подобной проблемой?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    asDb, err := database.AerospikeOpenClusterConnection(database.NewClusterConfig(AEROSPIKE), nil)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Console.Critical(console.PrefixAerospike, fmt.Sprintf("invalid connect: %s", err.Error()))
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    config.UserRepository = aerospike.NewUser2VRepository(asDb, os.Getenv(AEROSPIKE_NAMESPACE))
```

Comment: покажите как вы клиента инициализируте?  один клиент на весь проект же?

Comment: Да совершенно. верно. Инициализация коннекта идет один раз. И дальше он раскидывается между репозиториями которые работают с этой бд.

Comment: asDb, err := database.AerospikeOpenClusterConnection(database.NewClusterConfig(`AEROSPIKE`), nil)
     if err != nil {
      logger.Console.Critical(console.PrefixAerospike, fmt.Sprintf(`invalid connect: %s`, err.Error()))
      os.Exit(1)
     }
     config.UserRepository = aerospike.NewUser2VRepository(asDb, os.Getenv(`AEROSPIKE_NAMESPACE`))

Comment: Так же проблема замечается в пуле коннектов.

Comment: выглядит так, что у вас есть лимит на подключение со стороны сервера, а клиенты ждут пока подключатся

Comment: Ограничение есть но оно дефолтное со стороны клиента. Просто складывается ощущение что он не закрывает их после а работы а они остаются висеть. Так как даже когда RPS падает до 500 запросов ( ночью) открытые соединения продолжают расти. 
На Сервере ограничение в 50к коннектов стоит кна клиенте дефолтное в 256.